# option to continue with current encoding when opening corrupted file using OpenFile macro method

Tags: emeditor

While opening a partly corrupted file using [OpenFile](http://www.emeditor.org/en/macro_editor_editor_openfile.html) (encoding specified), there isn't an option to force it using the specified encoding, thus the macro is interrupted.

Is there an option in macro to force it "Continue opening as Current Encoding", instead of letting the user choose and continue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clear the **Prompt if Null Character Found** and **Prompt if Invalid Character Found** options in the **File** page of configuration properties of the file type. To do this in a macro, you can add the following code before **OpenFile**.

```
document.ConfigName = "Text";  // replace "Text" with the configuration of your file type
cfg = document.Config;
cfg.File.PromptInvalid = false;
cfg.File.PromptNull = false;
cfg.Save();
```